# CATextLayer wrapped sizeToFit?

Tags: core-animation, uilabel, core-text, catextlayer, sizetofit

If I set `textLayer.wrapped = YES`, how do I resize `textLayer` to contain the wrapped text? I.e., how do I get the new height of the `textLayer`?

Basically, I want something like `-[UILabel sizeToFit]`.

Comment: was wondering about that too..

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is get the size of the text.

Thankfully, the [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) offers a method to do exactly that:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

That will give you a `CGSize` that you can then use to set the frame of your `UILabel` or whatever subclass of `UIView` that you're using.

So, assuming `textLayer` is a `UILabel` - rather than a `CALayer` - you'll end up with something like this:

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
CGSize myFontSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont];
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myFontSize.width, myFontSize.height)];
myLabel.text = newTitle;
myLabel.font = myFont;
```