# What is the CALayer equivalent to UIView's sizeToFit-method?

Tags: uiview, resize, calayer, sizetofit

I'm searching for a way to let a CALayer resize itself whenever its sublayers change (which means either when the bounds of any sublayer change or when the sublayer array itself changes).

When i worked with views before, i managed that through implementing sizeThatFits in my custom UIView subclass, which was called automatically by sizeToFit whenever the view's subviews changed.

Since CALayer has the sizeThatFits-equivalent-method preferredSize, i was surprised not to find a sizeToFit-equivalent.

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219588/catextlayer-wrapped-sizetofit

Comment: i think that's about sizeThatFits, not sizeToFit, since he wants to know what the size of the layer should be. I'm able to calculate that size (via preferredSize), but i need a method which gets called whenever the subviews change (which then would call preferredSize and set the layer's frame accordingly).

Comment: Why don't just use a UIView instead?

Comment: CALayer just seems to fit better, i don't need touch handling, i get implicit animations and i don't have to bother about forwarding touches which were sent to it. Moreover the layer-version should be a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement(override) the  `- (void)layoutSublayers`
... 
 *Subclasses can override this to
 * provide their own layout algorithm, which should set the frame of
 * each sublayer

```
- (void)layoutSublayers
{
 // self.frame = aNewSubLayer.bounds
// basically do algorithm for setting frame and bounds for this(self) layer and subLayers here
}
```